# Is there a way to get all bindings of a JavaFX property?

Tags: java, javafx

The title says it all, but to elaborate: if I add one or more bindings to some property, is there a way to get and examine them later? I would expect there is getBindings() method in the Property class, but obviously there isn't.

Comment: Ref this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking for a solution for this, I came to realization that getBindings() method probably doesn't exist because there is no elegant way to implement it, due to Binding being a parameterized type. Workaround is to track bindings yourself, but it is difficult to do without resorting to raw types. One way is to use [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). BTW, the same goes for listeners and event handlers.